# Adding a CheckBox to a singlechoice set AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, customization, android-alertdialog, radiobuttonlist

I want to add a checkbox to this standard AlertDialog wiht a single choice list

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.difficultyLevel_list, 1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { level = which; }
})
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
.show();
```

Right now as it is, it shows nicely:

[image]

I shifted to use custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/levels_keep"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/levels_keep" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/levels_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/difficultyLevel_list"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Using this code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
final View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_levels, null);
final ListView list = (ListView) customView.findViewById(R.id.levels_list);
final CheckBox keep = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.levels_keep);
// list.setSelected(level);
list.setItemChecked(level, true); // Marks the item as checked
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        level = position;
    }
});

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setView(customView)
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        CheckBox keep = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.levels_keep);
        if( keep.isChecked() ) {
            Context context = PlayersActivity.this;
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString(context.getString(R.string.pref_level_key), String.valueOf(level));
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
.show();
```

Which shows (the List is scrollable):

[image]

There are several things I cannot figure out:

1. Why I don't see radio buttons on the list?
2. <strike>How do I set a default checked item?</strike> (Edited the code with the solution)
3. <strike>How do I listen to changes in the selection?</strike> (Edited the code, since I found how to do it)
4. How can I add padding between the checkbox square and the checkbox text. I tried android:paddingLeft but is makes it worse, overlapping text and square. I tried android:drawablePadding to no effect.
5. Why the theme has changed ? (no really important, just curious) **Edit** It seems that the theme colors are all messed up, when I click on an item its text color becomes black and "dissapear" into the row's background

Comment: Please don't prefix your question's title with *Android* as it just adds noise, the tag at the bottom is more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why I don't see radio buttons on the list?

It appears that setting the `android:entries` attribute makes the `ListView` to create an `ArrayAdapter` using `com.android.internal.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as the layout. I don't know if that layout fully replicates the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` layout but if it does then it's just a `TextView` so no `CheckBox` is available.

> How do I set a default checked item?

If what I said above is true, then remove the `entries` attribute and set the adapter for the *levels_list* `ListView` in code using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` as the row layout.

> How do I listen to changes in the selection?

Set a `OnItemClickListener` on the `ListView` from the layout.

> How can I add padding between the checkbox square and the checkbox
>   text. I tried android:paddingLeft but is makes it worse, overlapping
>   text and square. I tried android:drawablePadding to no effect.

Use a simple `CheckBox` and a `TextView` instead of just a `CheckBox` and you could place those as you please.

> Why the theme has changed ? (no really important, just curious)

I'm not sure. First of all, as I said above the `ListView` uses a special layout(which I don't know how it's styled) and also you're using a custom view instead of the normal `ListView` content which again could be styled differently.

If you just want a `ChekcBox` in the title, why not just [set a custom title](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setCustomTitle%28android.view.View%29) on the `AlertDialog` and continue to use `setSingleChoiceItems`?

**Edited by the OP with the solution**

I post the working code here, since it is definitely bases on Luksprog answer, and i want to mark it as the answer. This code was tested and works fine.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
final View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_levels, null);
final ListView list = (ListView) customView.findViewById(R.id.levels_list);
final CheckBox keep = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.levels_keep);
String [] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.difficultyLevel_list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, items);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setItemChecked(level, true);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        level = position;
    }
});

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setView(customView)
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        MyLog.w(TAG,"Level is " + level);
        if( keep.isChecked() ) {
            Context context = PlayersActivity.this;
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString(context.getString(R.string.pref_level_key), String.valueOf(level));
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
.show();
```

Comment: thanks. The check box is not the title, I put it on top because otherwise, depending on the device, it is placed out of screen. And I would have to envelope all in vertical scroll to get to it. This way the checkbox is always visible and the ListView can scroll, by definitnion.

Comment: @ilomambo If you have also set a title for the `AlertDialog` my advice is not useful. Set the adapter for the `ListView` in code. Also, shouldn't you look for the `CheckBox` in the dialog like : `((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(etc)`? Now it works?

Comment: See my latest edits, I found solutions to questions 2 & 3, the code I edited to reflect that, it includes geting the view IDs for the checkbox and listview.

Comment: Yes, I edited your answer to include the working code, so I can mark it as answered. Waiting for peer review acceptance of the edit, when it is accepted, I'll mark the answer. Thank you.